# Served images through PHP won't load in Shadowbox

Tags: php, shadowbox

I've been using shadowbox without issue on my sites without issue for a while now. I've created a PHP file to serve media content from a protected folder. Here is what is in the download.php:

```
<?php
$fullpath="/home/user/media/image1.jpg";
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='.basename($filename));    
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($fullpath));
readfile($fullpath);
exit;
?>
```

This works well if I call it using an IMG tag or try and download the image. For example:

```
<img src="download.php?id=123" />
```

However, if I use shadowbox the browser darkens and I don't even get a loading animation and nothing displays.

```
<a href="download.php?id=358" rel="shadowbox[test]"><img src="download.php?id=358"/></a>
```

The image will display fine with the example above, but the shadowbox won't load when clicked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get any JS console errors in Firebug or Developer tools?

Comment: I can't see any errors; it's acting like it's loading the .php file as an image. I've tried in Firefox/Firebug and Chrome.

Comment: are you on Apache and .htaccess is allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem—for your case—is, Shadowbox check for file extension before fetching the content. If you search inside shadowbox.js (try search for img.ext), you will find this somewhere:

`img.ext=["bmp","gif","jpg","jpeg","png"];`

So, you could try adding PHP to loosen it a bit and Shadowbox will happily grab your image:

`img.ext=["bmp","gif","jpg","jpeg","png","php"];`

Or, you could save your php file as jpg (sounds weird, no?) and force the server to process it as a php file. For example, if you use Apache and `.htaccess` is allowed, you could try creating `.htaccess` (or adding these line to existing `.htaccess` file) with:

```
<files download.jpg>
  ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</files>
```

Comment: That worked great! I added PHP tot he list of images and now it loads up just fine. I'll have to vote this up when I get enough cred... :/

Comment: Amazing, this has plagued the annals of my programming subconscious  for months!!

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't turning php on on images at the htaccess level be a huge security risk?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind what you are saying but isn't it important to not put information out there that creates security risks? I don't have a rep of fifty because I very rarely have to post anything on stack but this screamed irresponsibility , providing an answer like this without warning of consequences.